# How to keep cycles material when exporting to unity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, unity, baking

I have an example of what I mean, for this I use a cube adding a simple cycles material I select toon[image]

How do I bake this material, thanks for reading.

Cheers!

Comment: You need to bake the materials.